# Maintaining Label Position in Front of Image (stretch mode is uniform) Regardless of Resizing of the Window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What i'm trying to do is having an image that describe something with content in and there is an indicators in the image (the image is already like this)

ex: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLbkP.jpg)

And my labels will cover these yellow parts

and after placing them, the should stay covering the same part regardless of the window size.

I have tried various things, starting from [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139216/A-Simple-Technique-for-Data-binding-to-the-Positio). and after many tries here is my current code, the problem in it is:

1- It should be already follow the same position but i don't find it working.

2- I don't think my approach is the right way to do this, i'm certain there should be an easier way.

First: Window1.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--
    A data-template that defines the visuals for a rectangle.
    -->
    <DataTemplate 
        DataType="{x:Type local:RectangleViewModel}"
        >
        <Grid>
            <Thumb
                Width="20"
                Height="20"
                DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta"
                >                    
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border
                            Background="Blue"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            >
                            <Viewbox>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ImageWidth ,FallbackValue=1}" />
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>                        
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- 
    Initialise the view model that supplies the UI with data.
    -->
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid Background="Aqua">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/1111.png" SizeChanged="Image_SizeChanged" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    <!--
    This ItemsControl presents the colored rectangles.
    The data-template that defines the visuals for each rectangle is in the 
    resources section at the start of this file.
    -->
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}"
        >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter
                    Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding X}"
                    />
                <Setter
                    Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Y}"
                    />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Second: Window1.xaml.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace SampleCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SizeChanged += Window1_SizeChanged;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the resize of the window
        /// </summary>
        private void Window1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Size oldSize = e.PreviousSize;

            Size newSize = e.NewSize;

            ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).Rectangles.ToList().ForEach(i => i.update(newSize));

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Hundle the resize of the window
        /// </summary>
        private void Image_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).Rectangles.ToList().ForEach(i => i.ImageSize = e.NewSize);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the user dragging the rectangle.
        /// </summary>
        private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Thumb thumb = (Thumb)sender;
            RectangleViewModel myRectangle = (RectangleViewModel)thumb.DataContext;

            //
            // Update the the position of the rectangle in the view-model.
            //
            myRectangle.X += e.HorizontalChange;
            myRectangle.Y += e.VerticalChange;
        }
    }
}
```

Third: ViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace SampleCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A simple example of a view-model.  
    /// </summary>
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Data Members

        /// <summary>
        /// The list of rectangles that is displayed in the ListBox.
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel> rectangles = new ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The image size
        /// </summary>
        private Size _imageSize ;

        #endregion Data Members
        public Size ImageSize
        {
            get => _imageSize; set
            {
                {
                    if (_imageSize == value)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    _imageSize = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ImageWidth");
                };
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            // Populate the view model with some example data.
            var r1 = new RectangleViewModel();
            rectangles.Add(r1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The list of rectangles that is displayed in the ListBox.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel> Rectangles
        {
            get
            {
                return rectangles;
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 'PropertyChanged' event that is raised when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Forth: RectangleViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows;

namespace SampleCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the view-model for a simple displayable rectangle.
    /// </summary>
    public class RectangleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Data Members

        /// <summary>
        /// The X coordinate of the location of the rectangle (in content coordinates).
        /// </summary>
        private double x;

        /// <summary>
        /// The Y coordinate of the location of the rectangle (in content coordinates).
        /// </summary>
        private double y;

        /// <summary>
        /// The size of the current window
        /// </summary>
        public Size mCurrentWindwoSize;

        #endregion Data Members

        public RectangleViewModel()
        {
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The size of the background image
        /// </summary>
        public Size ImageSize { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The X coordinate of the location of the rectangle (in content coordinates).
        /// </summary>
        public double X
        {
            get
            {
                return (mCurrentWindwoSize.Width-ImageSize.Width)/2 + Data.x * ImageSize.Width;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((mCurrentWindwoSize.Width - ImageSize.Width) / 2 + Data.x * ImageSize.Width == value)return;
                Data.x =( value - (mCurrentWindwoSize.Width - ImageSize.Width) / 2 )/ ImageSize.Width;
                OnPropertyChanged("X");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Y coordinate of the location of the rectangle (in content coordinates).
        /// </summary>
        public double Y
        {
            get
            {
                return (mCurrentWindwoSize.Height - ImageSize.Height) / 2 + Data.y * ImageSize.Height;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((mCurrentWindwoSize.Height - ImageSize.Height) / 2 + Data.y * ImageSize.Height == value) return;
                Data.y = (value - (mCurrentWindwoSize.Height - ImageSize.Height) / 2) / ImageSize.Height;
                OnPropertyChanged("Y");
            }
        }

        public void update(Size size)
        {
            mCurrentWindwoSize = size;
            OnPropertyChanged("X");
            OnPropertyChanged("Y");
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 'PropertyChanged' event that is raised when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Fifth: Data.cs

```
namespace SampleCode
{
    public static class Data
    {
        public static double x = 0.5;//default
        public static double y = 0.5;//default
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it,

The main issue was that i forget that the windows upper panel and border are included in ActualWidth and ActualHeight, and after some fixes here is the final code:

First: Window1.xaml

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <!--
    A data-template that defines the visuals for a rectangle.
    -->
    <DataTemplate 
        DataType="{x:Type local:RectangleViewModel}"
        >
        <Grid>
            <Thumb
                Width="{Binding LabelWidth}"
                Height="{Binding LabelWidth}"
                DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta"
                >                    
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border 
                            Background="Blue"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            >
                            <Viewbox>
                                <TextBlock Text="1" />
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>                        
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- 
    Initialise the view model that supplies the UI with data.
    -->
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid Background="Aqua">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/1112.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    <!--
    This ItemsControl presents the colored rectangles.
    The data-template that defines the visuals for each rectangle is in the 
    resources section at the start of this file.
    -->
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}"
        >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas SizeChanged="Canvas_SizeChanged"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter
                    Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding X}"
                    />
                <Setter
                    Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Y}"
                    />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Second: Window1.xaml.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace SampleCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the user dragging the rectangle.
        /// </summary>
        private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Thumb thumb = (Thumb)sender;
            RectangleViewModel myRectangle = (RectangleViewModel)thumb.DataContext;

            //
            // Update the the position of the rectangle in the view-model.
            //
            myRectangle.X += e.HorizontalChange;
            myRectangle.Y += e.VerticalChange;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Hundle the resize of the canvas
        /// </summary>
        private void Canvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Size newSize = e.NewSize;

            ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).Rectangles.ToList().ForEach(i => i.update(e.NewSize));

        }
    }
}
```

Third: ViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace SampleCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A simple example of a view-model.  
    /// </summary>
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Data Members

        /// <summary>
        /// The list of rectangles that is displayed in the ListBox.
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel> rectangles = new ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel>();

        #endregion

        public ViewModel()
        {
            // Populate the view model with some example data.
            var r1 = new RectangleViewModel(0.1,0.3);
            rectangles.Add(r1);

            var r2 = new RectangleViewModel(0.2,0.4);
            rectangles.Add(r2);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The list of rectangles that is displayed in the ListBox.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel> Rectangles
        {
            get
            {
                return rectangles;
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 'PropertyChanged' event that is raised when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and Finally, Forth: RectabgleViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows;

namespace SampleCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the view-model for a simple displayable rectangle.
    /// </summary>
    public class RectangleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Data Members

        /// <summary>
        /// The aspect ration of the image
        /// </summary>
        private double ratio = 1.375;

        /// <summary>
        /// The label width
        /// </summary>
        private double mLabelWidth = 20;

        /// <summary>
        /// The X coordinate of the location of the rectangle (in content coordinates).
        /// </summary>
        private double mX;

        /// <summary>
        /// The Y coordinate of the location of the rectangle (in content coordinates).
        /// </summary>
        private double mY;

        /// <summary>
        /// The size of the current window
        /// </summary>
        public Size mCurrentWindwoSize = new Size(450,300);

        /// <summary>
        /// The size of the label as a percantage from the image size
        /// </summary>
        private readonly double sizePercentage = 0.05;

        #endregion Data Members

        public RectangleViewModel(double x, double y)
        {
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The size of the background image
        /// </summary>
        public Size ImageSize { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The width of the label
        /// </summary>
        public double LabelWidth
        {
            get { return mLabelWidth; }
            set { if (value == mLabelWidth)
                    return;
                else
                    mLabelWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LabelWidth");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The X coordinate of the location of the rectangle (in content coordinates).
        /// </summary>
        public double X
        {
            get
            {
                return (mCurrentWindwoSize.Width-ImageSize.Width)/2 + mX * ImageSize.Width - mLabelWidth/2;
            }
            set
            {
                //if ((mCurrentWindwoSize.Width - ImageSize.Width) / 2 + mX * ImageSize.Width == value)return;
                mX =( value - (mCurrentWindwoSize.Width - ImageSize.Width) / 2 + mLabelWidth/2)/ ImageSize.Width;
                OnPropertyChanged("X");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Y coordinate of the location of the rectangle (in content coordinates).
        /// </summary>
        public double Y
        {
            get
            {
                return (mCurrentWindwoSize.Height - ImageSize.Height) / 2 + mY * ImageSize.Height - mLabelWidth/2 ;
            }
            set
            {
                //if ((mCurrentWindwoSize.Height - ImageSize.Height) / 2 + mY * ImageSize.Height == value) return;
                mY = (value - (mCurrentWindwoSize.Height - ImageSize.Height) / 2 + mLabelWidth/2) / ImageSize.Height;
                OnPropertyChanged("Y");
            }
        }

        public void update(Size windowSize)
        {
            mCurrentWindwoSize = windowSize;

            if (windowSize.Height > windowSize.Width * ratio)
            {
                ImageSize = new Size(windowSize.Width, windowSize.Width * ratio);
            }
            else
            {
                ImageSize = new Size(windowSize.Height / ratio, windowSize.Height);
            }

            LabelWidth = ImageSize.Width * sizePercentage;

            X = (mCurrentWindwoSize.Width - ImageSize.Width) / 2 + mX * ImageSize.Width - mLabelWidth/2;

            Y = (mCurrentWindwoSize.Height - ImageSize.Height) / 2 + mY * ImageSize.Height - mLabelWidth/2;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 'PropertyChanged' event that is raised when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

    }
}
```

I think that it still needs some clean up but at least it do the job required by it.
I will try to make it cleaner while moving it to the actual project.

Thanks.